# How to add new generic attribute in jQuery FormBuilder

Tags: javascript, jquery, formbuilder

I'm using jQuery FormBuilder (https://formbuilder.online/) and I need one custom attribute as a Checkbox for every type. So independently from whether it's a textarea, text input, checkbox or similarly - I always want to add the same checkbox as a new attribute.

My options look like this:

```
options = {
    scrollToFieldOnAdd: false,
    disableFields: ['button', 'file', 'hidden'],
    disabledAttrs: ['access'],
    // Add custom checkbox property to the form
    typeUserAttrs: {
        text: {
            showInGroupDesc: {
                type: 'checkbox',
                label: 'Show in Group Desc.?'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which makes use of `typeUserAttrs`, unfortunately I have to specify exactly the type of field where I want to add the new attribute `showInGroupDesc` into.

I do not want to copy/paste this element in `typeUserAttrs` for every single type - is there a wildcard setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution myself by initializing an Object `userAttrs` with the new Attribute(s) `newAttributes` before passing it to `typeUserAttrs`:

```
// New attribute for specified fields 'fields' below
var newAttributes = {
            showInGroupDesc: {
                type: 'checkbox',
                label: 'Show in Group Desc.?'
            }
        };
var userAttrs = {};
const fields = ["autocomplete", "checkbox-group", "date", "number", "radio-group", "select", "text", "textarea"];
fields.forEach(function (item, index) {
    userAttrs[item] = newAttributes;
});

// Initialise the form builder
options = {
    // ... All your options here ...
    typeUserAttrs: userAttrs
  };
```